# Proof: triangle inequality Hermitian inner product

Tags: triangles, inner-products

How can I show the triangle inequality for the Hermitian inner product?

I started as follows (using linearity in the second component):
\begin{align}
0\leq\lVert v+w\rVert^2&=\langle v+w,v+w\rangle\\
&=\langle v+w,v\rangle +\langle v+w,w\rangle\\
&=\overline{\langle v,v+w\rangle}+\overline{\langle w,v+w}\rangle\\
&=\overline{\langle v,v\rangle}+\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}+\overline{\langle w,v\rangle}+\overline{\langle w,w\rangle}\\
&=\langle v,v\rangle +\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}+\langle v,w\rangle +\langle w,w\rangle\\
&=\lVert v\rVert ++\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}+\langle v,w\rangle+\lVert w\rVert.
\end{align}
However, what I need is the following:
$$
\lvert\langle v,w\rangle\rvert\leq\lVert v\rVert \cdot\lVert w\rVert,
$$
where $\lvert z\rvert$ stands for the modulus of $z\in\mathbb C$. I feel like I need to go to this form:
$$
\lvert\langle v,w\rangle\rvert^2=\langle v,w\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle v,w\rangle} \leq\lVert v\rVert \cdot\lVert w\rVert.
$$
How can I turn $\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}+\langle v,w\rangle$ into $\langle v,w\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\langle v,w \rangle = z$, you have shown that
$$ \lVert v+w \rVert^2 = \lVert v \rVert^2 + 2\Re{(z)} + \lVert w \rVert^2. $$
Written like this, it is clear that $ \lvert z \rvert = \sqrt{\Re(z)^2+\Im(z)^2} \geqslant \Re(z) $, so
$$ \lVert v \rVert^2 + 2\Re{(z)} + \lVert w \rVert^2 \leqslant \lVert v \rVert^2 + 2\lvert \langle v,w \rangle \rvert + \lVert w \rVert^2. $$
One can then use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $ \lvert \langle v,w \rangle \rvert \leqslant \lVert v \rVert \lVert w \rVert $ and factorise to finish the job.